# The selected item does not display when I use DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using the following to generate a drop down list:

```
@for (var index = 0; index < Model.AdminSummaries.Count(); index++) 
            { 
            <div class="rep_tr0"> 
                <div class="rep_td0"> 
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status, 
                       AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(),
                       new { id = string.Format("Status_{0}",index ) })
                 </div> 
            </div>
            }
```

Here's the HTML it generates:

```
<select id="Status_1" name="AdminSummaries[1].Status"><option value="1">Released</option>
<option value="2">Review</option>
<option value="3">New</option>
</select>
```

Here's the class that gives the status options.

```
public static class AdminStatusReference
{

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAdminStatusOptions()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Released"  },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Review" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "New" }
            };
    }

}
```

Everything works good EXCEPT it doesn't select the items correctly. There's no option with 'selected' to match the data in the AdminSummaries.

How can I make it so the correct select list items are selected?

Just to clarify this. My problem is that if there is a data record with a value of 3 for the status then when I look at the screen I see a select list with the word "Release" showing.

What I need is for the select list to show text that corresponds with the data value.

Comment: What type has your model property `Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status`? If its an enum type, try changing it to `int`.

Comment: public string Status { get; set; }

Comment: public string Status { get; set; }  - I changed to int but still doesn't work.

Comment: Im using here exactly the same DropDownFor code with a list property of type IEnumerable<SelectListItem> and a value property of type int and it works. Can you please double check, that your Status is an int and contains a valid value (i.e. 2)?

Comment: public IList<AdminSummary> AdminSummaries { get; set; }

    public class AdminSummary
    {
        public int Status { get; set; }  I have a selection fo 2s and 3s in my data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the more accurate answer

```
public static class AdminStatusReference 
{ 
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAdminStatusOptionsFor(AdminSummaries arg) 
    { 
        var options = new[] 
            { 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Released" }, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Review" }, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "New" } 
            }; 
        options.First(o=> o.Value == arg).Selected = true;
        return options; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand anything about what you are saying. The class you want me to change provides reference data. Why would I be changing that class? My point is that when the view is displayed the DropDownListFor does not match up the actual data item with the select list.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SelectListItem.Selected` property to `true`:

```
public static class AdminStatusReference 
{ 

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAdminStatusOptions() 
    { 
        return new[] 
            { 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Released", Selected = true  }, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Review" }, 
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "New" } 
            }; 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Sorry but what are you saying? This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: @Melissa what I'm saying is that when you create an instance of the `SelectListItem` that you want to be selected initially, you just need to initialize the `Selected` property to `true`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I am sorry but your answer makes no sense at all

Comment: Well I think it's always the case that when people use a select drop down list they want the item that appears to be selected to line up with the item in the data. I am not so concerned about the initial setting. The problem is if the data has a setting of review then when I look at the screen I see "Released"

Comment: The two answers above are correct. Send me an email ( rick.anderson at microsoft.com) and I'll send you my pending DDL tutorial. When you don't have a selected item, browser default to the first list entry, which in your case is Released.

Comment: Doesn't the Html.DropDownListFor take into account the current data for the row and add the "selected" to the option that matches?

Answer (score 1):

It seams from the source code that the `DropDownListFor` method (actually the `ViewDataEvaluator.Eval` method) doesn't support expressions containing indexers. Because your expression: `AdminSummaries[index].Status` contains an indexer that's why the framework doesn't use the selected value from your model class.
 The only solution is to specify the selected item when setting the `SelectListItem` collection, you can do this by passing the currently selected value to your `GetAdminStatusOptions` method:

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status,
    AdminStatusReference.GetAdminStatusOptions(Model.AdminSummaries[index].Status),
    new { id = string.Format("Status_{0}",index ) })
```

A sample GetAdminStatusOptions implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAdminStatusOptions(string selected = null)
{
    var options = new[]
                      {
                          new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Released"},
                          new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Review"},
                          new SelectListItem {Value = "3", Text = "New"}
                      };
    foreach (var option in options)
    {
        option.Selected = option.Value == selected;
    }
    return options;
}
```

Comment: My solution was to reimplement `DropDownListFor` that used `ModelMetadata` and `ExpressionHelper` instead of `Eval` - back in 2013 for MVC 2.0. It's now 2016 and the latest releases of ASP.NET MVC still have this issue.